# uploadify - possible to have multiple links to prompt the user to select a file?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using uploadify. which by default shows a Browse File image that when clicked loads a prompt for the user to select 1 or more files.

I'd like to have 2 places on my page that active the File Browser.

Is there a way to add an addition link that isn't directly attached to uploadify, but can call some JS function that opens the file browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the answer is no. Uploadify works by embedding a flash animation in place of the file input. For security reasons, only the flash button can activate the file browse prompt. As of Flash 10, it cannot be fired via JavaScript.

Of course you can probably find a way to fake it by just using two uploadify instances on the same page and have them target the same queue (not sure if uploadify supports this natively or if you would have to hack it).

More info:
http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=423